# use sql command more than once with different commands

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

I've been trying to use the same `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects to execute to different commands.

the first one checks for duplicate and the second one inserts the data if the data the user entered is not a duplicate.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
        {
            string Command = "SELECT CountryName FROM [Countries] WHERE CountryName = @Name";

            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(Command, conn))
            {
                comm.Parameters.Add("@Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
                comm.Parameters["@Name"].Value = Name;

                comm.Parameters.Add("@IsVisible", System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit);
                comm.Parameters["@IsVisible"].Value = IsVisible;

                conn.Open();

                if (comm.ExecuteScalar() == null)
                {
                        Command = "INSERT INTO [Countries] (CountryName, IsVisible) VALUES (@Name, @IsVisible);";
                        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
        }
```

I was trying to save a trip to the database by using one connection.

**The Problem is:**

> The first command runs okay but the
>   second command which inserts into the
>   database won't work (it doesn't add
>   any records to the db) and when I
>   tried to display the rows affected it
>   gave me -1 !!

**The Question is:**

> Is this is the ideal way to check for
>   a duplicate records to constraint a
>   unique country ? and why the second
>   command is not executing ?

Comment: You don't explicitly *need* to use the same DB connection to save a trip to the database because [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) is almost certainly being used (except if you've explicitly disabled it). If you execute twice (using the same connection or not), there will be two calls to the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the tip +1 .. but in your opinion, do you think that there's a way to save a trip to reduce the load on the Db in my situation or not ?

Comment: Most definitely if you use a stored procedure. Would that be an option?

Comment: @IKashef: the way described in my answer (putting a DB constraint on the column and handling the thrown exception in case of a duplicate) entails only a single trip to the DB.

Comment: @steinar, it is an option but do you have any code in mind for the stored procedure ? .. I mean how do I check if the name exists after I try to SELECt it !?

Comment: @MusiGenesis, I Think putting a constraint and handling the exception is a good idea and specially it will be rare to have a duplicate record (it's just to secure the application).

Comment: @IKashef: it wasn't my idea - it's long been considered a best practice for this sort of task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you rewrite the `Command` variable with the insert statement, you are simply modifying the string named `Command` that you've defined earlier.  You are not modifying the command text stored inside of the `SqlCommand` object.

Try:

> comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Countries] (CountryName, IsVisible) VALUES (@Name, @IsVisible);";

Comment: That was simple .. Thank you =)

Answer (score 3):

You are changing the value of `string Command`, but you are never actually changing the command string in `SqlCommand comm`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question:  no, this is not the way to ensure uniqueness for country name.  In your database, you should define your Countries table so that CountryName is the primary key (alternatively, you can declare some other column as the PK and define a unique constraint on CountryName).

The attempt to insert a duplicate value, then, will throw an exception, which you can handle appropriately (discard the existing record, overwrite it, prompt the user for a different value etc.).

Checking for uniqueness via your method is considered bad because A) it places logic that belongs in the database itself into your application's code; and B) it introduces a potential race condition, wherein some other application or thread inserts a value in between your read of the database and your write to it.

Comment: +1 .. I wish I could also mark this as an answer .. but my original question about "why don't I get the expected output" .. but I think you're really right about handling the exception instead. altough number B is a little vogue to me! =)

Comment: @IKashef: B is relatively rare, although in environments where many different threads are accessing the database simultaneously it will happen often enough for you to lose your job. :)  I've inherited many apps/databases written by others over the years, and in every situation where the developer relied on his application code to ensure uniqueness, there were numerous duplicates in the tables. It's an approach that is guaranteed to eventually not work.

Comment: You just saved me! .. because my application allows more than one guy to add stuff and there will be times when we'll need all the team to be data entering stuff! .. Thanks a lot and if you have any articles about to avoid this issue when the database is manipulated or accessed simultaneously please post it ..+1

Comment: These guys are pretty good for ASP.NET: http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/default.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure if this is appropriate but If you have the time to look at this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466771/stored-procedure-or-bulk-statements I'd really appreciate it. =) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I thing i suggest to seperate the insert with your select statement..
someting like:

```
    private void Insert()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr)) 
         {             
        string Command = "INSERT INTO [Countries] (CountryName, IsVisible) VALUES (@Name, @IsVisible)";    

        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(Command, conn)) 
         {
        comm.Parameters.Add("@Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20); 
        comm.Parameters["@Name"].Value = Name;
        comm.Parameters.Add("@IsVisible", System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit);                 comm.Parameters["@IsVisible"].Value = IsVisible;
        conn.Open(); 

        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
        } 

}
```

---

```
private void SelectInsert()
{
      using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr)) 
     {             
    string Command = "SELECT CountryName FROM [Countries] WHERE CountryName = @Name";              
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(Command, conn)) 
     {
    comm.Parameters.Add("@Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20); 
    comm.Parameters["@Name"].Value = Name;

    conn.Open(); 
    if (comm.ExecuteScalar() == null)
    { 

           Insert(); //your save method

     }
    } 
}
```

Regards

Comment: thanks for your time :) .. but changing the CommandText did the trick! =)